# Magento2 - Layout block do not work with cache enabled

Tags: magento2, layout, cache

I created my custom Block (php class), I add this Block inside two different containers on different blocks in xml file, each block also has a different `.phtml`

My php block is customizable by arguments passed via xml.

If I disable the cache, my blocks works fine. While with the cache enabled, I get twice the first block.

Here my code:

In `<vendor>/<module>/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceContainer name="evidenza">
            <block class="<Vendor>\<Module>\Block\ProductsList" name="product-evidenza" template="<Vendor>_<Module>::grid.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title_1" xsi:type="string">IN</argument>
                    <argument name="title_2" xsi:type="string">EVIDENZA</argument>
                    <argument name="title_span_class" xsi:type="string">red-satur-text</argument>
                    <argument name="products_count" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
                    <argument name="type_grid" xsi:type="string">evidenza</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="ispirazioni">
            <block class="<Vendor>\<Module>\Block\ProductsList" name="product-ispirazioni" template="<Vendor>_<Module>::ispirazioni.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title_1" xsi:type="string">ISPIRAZIONI</argument>
                    <argument name="products_count" xsi:type="string">2</argument>
                    <argument name="type_grid" xsi:type="string">ispirazioni</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </referenceContainer>
</body></page>
```

My php Block is used only to get the collection of the products in different ways according to the xml arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove attribute cache="false" in the tag of the layout.xml